# Find all numbers on a line after a specific word

Tags: python, regex

I have the following:

```py
YTD     6.42%   7.17%
1 month 2.75%   2.61%
3 months 8.97%   7.07%
1 year  8.94%   10.89%
3 years 9.05%   9.31%
5 years 12.43%  15.06%
```

I need to extract all the numbers after the corresponding keyword. For example, if I look for `YTD`, it should give `['6.42%', '7.17%']`, if I look for 1 year, it should give `['8.94%', '10.89%']`.

So far, I have

```
match = re.search(r'(?<=YTD).*(\d+([\,\.]\d+)?%)', txt)
```

which gives

```
'\t6.42%\t7.17%'
```

The issue with this is that it gives me both numbers, but with '\t' as well.

Any pointers to what I am doing wrong will be most helpful.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You need to work through tutorials on some basic Python data structures.

Comment: The sample data is presented in a wrong way. From the sample output, columns are delimited by tabs, but the data didn't show that.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is actually what I have:
    
     \nYTD\t6.42%\t7.17%\n1 month\t2.75%\t2.61%\n3 months\t8.97%\t7.07%\n1 year\t8.94%\t10.89%\n3 years\t9.05%\t9.31%\n5 years\t12.43%\t15.06%

(I am sorry, I do not know how to put it in code format while commenting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and

```py
import regex
reg = regex.compile(r'(?<=YTD.*)\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?%')
txt = """YTD     6.42%   7.17%
1 month 2.75%   2.61%
3 months 8.97%   7.07%
1 year  8.94%   10.89%
3 years 9.05%   9.31%
5 years 12.43%  15.06%"""
print(regex.findall(reg, txt))
```

See [proof](https://tio.run/##LY/LDoJADEX38xUNyQRGScPwxkjY@AlujLoggkLCK8Ms4OuxI3bR3p7cNu206mYcgm1r@2lUGlT9qRdGGfJd42vsp7arHWU7xTm/XS94EI/q6BSnu4tPUqLgtmB60TRiWRY5wESMoc@pJigTziT046Ab8DGJDPUxlpwFO50hxSzZzd7PvNalAkNDQ6WHaWbcBs@QoffbkWFAO6I/lT6GAWEZoRdzOoRNqh20s3/xboeq7DrTuUC3CrFtXw).

**Results**: `['6.42%', '7.17%']`.

**Expression explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    YTD                      'YTD'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,.]                     any character of: ',', '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %                        '%'
```

Comment: what's the advantage comparing to built-in `re`?

Comment: @Marat The non-fixed width lookbehind pattern is not supported by `re`.

Comment: Thank you! It did sove my problem. I was just stuck using the built-in `re` that didn't think on using `PyPi regex`